# CPAN install GD fails

Tags: perl, gd, cpan

I've hit a roadblock installing GD with CPAN on a new server.  The relevant
error line is

> Can't load '/usr/local/lib/perl5/auto/GD/GD.so' for module GD:
>   /usr/local/lib/perl5/auto/GD/GD.so: undefined symbol:
>   gdImageCreateFromGd2Ptr at /usr/lib/perl5/DynaLoader.pm line 200.

While installing submodule GD::Graph

As far as I can tell, prerequisites libraries are all installed and up to date.

Comment: `prerequisites libraries are all installed and up to date`, How did you ensure that these Libraries are installed? this is an issue with missing `gd` libraries from your system. Use your system's package manager to install them.

Comment: I installed libgd and libpng using yum.  & anyway, if I were missing a package of that type then CPAN would either install it or tell me to, right?  I'm actually duplicating an existing system onto new hardware, so can use the old system for reference.   Maybe it's skew due to incidental version upgrades.  I see reference in current gd to reinstating gif format support.

Comment: What OS flavor are you using? debian? do `apt-get install libgd2-xpm` or better yet `apt-get install libgd-gd2-perl`

Comment: @ddyer, `if I were missing a package of that type then CPAN would either install it or tell me to, right?`, wrong, CPAN won't tell you what package you are missing, instead, it will tell you what files you are missing, then you have to install the package that contain those files using your operating systems package manager. Also, `CPAN` wont install operating system packages. It will install other CPAN modules which are dependencies, not the packages.

Comment: It's more likely there's either a linking issue or a library mismatch than missing libraries. @nrathaus The OP already mentioned he's using `yum`.

Comment: He mentioned it in the comment, didn't see it @chrsblck

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why bother with `CPAN`. You are using `yum`. Make your life easy. This is a quick test I did on my RHEL 6.4 machine:

```
# uname -a
Linux ip-10-227-20-6 2.6.32-358.14.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Jun 17 15:54:20 EDT 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago)

# yum install perl-GDGraph.noarch

# perl -e 'use GD::Graph'
#
```

the `yum install perl-GDGraph.noarch` command will install below dependency packages:

```
(1/5): gd-2.0.35-11.el6.x86_64.rpm
(2/5): libXpm-3.5.10-2.el6.x86_64.rpm
(3/5): perl-GD-2.44-3.el6.x86_64.rpm
(4/5): perl-GDGraph-1.44-7.el6.noarch.rpm
(5/5): perl-GDTextUtil-0.86-15.el6.noarch.rpm
```

And it will install `GD::Graph` too :)

Comment: This worked after an additional step.  I had used "force" to install GD with CPAN.  I had to install GD with yum.  (still no joy) and then uninstall cpan gd using "App-pmuninstall".   My problem is fixed although the underlying problem remains a mystery.  Thanks.